# RestKit 0.10.1 with Core Data steep learning curve

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ios, core-data, restkit

I am currently in the following situation:

I am creating an iOS application and I would like to use RestKit hand in hand with Core Data. I am new to RestKit but really want to figure it out.

There are a few things I am having some trouble with:

1. How to keep my Core Data in sync with the server? If I delete an object or add and object on the server, how can I make sure Core Data gets updated? I have no problem with posting objects to the server but I also want to manage "inbound" changes.
2. I am having trouble finding up to date documentation and examples. Does anyone have up to date example of code that does this?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Take a look at the code in the RKTwitterCoreData example app that was included with your restkit download. It should get you some milage toward understanding this. Also, note that you'll want to read the documentation on RKObjectManager, which is the class you use instead of RKClient when mapping the JSON or XML response from your server to Core Data.

Comment: Thank you geraldWilliam this was exactly what I needed. I now have all the functionality I needed! Note to self: always venture into the "Examples" folder.

Comment: Cool, I'll post as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the code in the RKTwitterCoreData example app that was included with your restkit download. It should get you some milage toward understanding this. Also, note that you'll want to read the documentation on RKObjectManager, which is the class you use instead of RKClient when mapping the JSON or XML response from your server to Core Data.